# How to display all properties of all object of an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of words that are objects and i want to display all the properties of all the words. These are just two words. I actually have many more.

```
const words = [
{
word:'interrogate'
meaning:'Formally question'


},
{
word:'tiresome'
meaning:'fatiguing'


}

]
```

i tried

```
for(var tn= 0; tn<words.length-1; tn++){
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=words[tn].meaning;
            };
```

but nothing happened.
by the way, "result" is the id of the p tag where i want to display.

Comment: You need to append rather than overwriting. Otherwise you only see the last thing you assigned.

Comment: You're only showing the `meaning` property. Do you also want to see the `word` property? And why `length-1`? You're skipping the last element of the array.

Comment: length-1 because the indexes start at 0 but lengths start at 1, and i don't want to show the word property.

Comment: But the comparison is `<`, not `<=`. The index of the last element is `length-1`, you stop at `length-2`.

Comment: aah! i see. besides, what i was doing did work, just it was inside the wrong event listener, so it wasnt getting triggered when i thought it would.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = `<pre> {JSON.stringify(words, null, 2)} </pre>
```

```js
const words = [{
    word: 'interrogate',
    meaning: 'Formally question'
  },
  {
    word: 'tiresome',
    meaning: 'fatiguing'
  }
]

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = `<pre>${JSON.stringify(words, null, 2)}</pre>`;
```

```html
<div id='result'>Hello</div>
```

Also, you are missing ',' after each property in your object. Which is throwing error and not rendering anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append to the element, not overwrite it each time. You can use a `<ul>` to make a list of meanings, and use `appendChild()` to add an `<li>` for each meaning.

The limit of the `for` loop should be `tn < words.length`, don't subtract 1.

```js
const words = [{
    word: 'interrogate',
    meaning: 'Formally question'
  },
  {
    word: 'tiresome',
    meaning: 'fatiguing'
  }
];

for (var tn = 0; tn < words.length; tn++) {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerText = words[tn].meaning;
  document.getElementById("result").appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<ul id="result">
<ul>
```

Comment: yes, i wanted to have it where the user searches and it shows the meaning, which i got it to work.